# Django: How to apply conditional attribute to HTML element in template?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-templates

I have a checkbox in my Django jinja template. I want that checkbox to be checked if object boolean field is True.

My html element looks like:

```
<div class="checkbox"><label>
<input type="checkbox" name="sendEmail" checked="{{ customer.SendSms }}">
Send sms?
</label></div>
```

The problem is, checkbox is still checked when attribute `checked="False"`, it's becomes unchecked only when the `checked` attribute is not there.

So what i need is, put checked attribute into the html element only if  `customer.SendSms` is true.

I know something like

```
{% if customer.SendSms %}
//checked html element here
{% else %}
//unchecked element here
{% endif %}
```

possible but this does not look so pretty, is there any other good way to handle this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`yesno` template filter will do the job:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="sendSms" {{ customer.SendSms|yesno:"checked" }}>
```

Comment: Here's link that still works -- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#yesno

Answer (score 24):

Why not wrap the attribute in a conditional?

```
<input type="checkbox" name="sendEmail" {% if customer.SendSms %}checked{% endif %}>
```